# Show Vec3b pixel values in OpenCV Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I want to know the values in a Vec3b pixel in a Mat image.
I'm not really an OpenCV expert.My Vec3b is, and if I print the Vec3b :

```
Vec3b centralIntensity;
cx=70; cy=700;
centralIntensity = (Vec3b)imgTemp->at<Vec3b>(cx, cy);
cout<<"I:["<<cx<<","<<cy<<"]="<<centralIntensity<<endl;
```

I get:

> I:[70,700]=[150, 162, 160]

If i print the single values:

```
 cout<<"***Uchar:["<<cx<<","<<cy<<"]="<<int(centralIntensity[0])<<","<<int(centralIntensity[1])<<","<<int(centralIntensity[2])<<endl;
```

I get:

> Uchar:[70,700]=127,0,0

I noticed that if I change coordinates, the last print is always the same.
Since I have to compare intensity pixel on the different channels, what would be a good way to do it and to know pixel values in BGR channels?

***EDIT1: This is how I create my Mat image (I already have a Mat imgIn as input) and I show in another way Vec3b:

```
Mat *imgTemp;
uchar cblue, blue, cgreen;
imgTemp = new Mat(imgIn->size(), CV_8UC3);
imgIn->convertTo(*imgTemp, CV_8UC3);
Vec3b centralIntensity;
centralIntensity = (Vec3b)imgTemp->at<Vec3b>(cx, cy);
cout<<"I:["<<cx<<","<<cy<<"]="<<centralIntensity<<endl;
centralIntensity[0] = cblue;
centralIntensity[1] = cgreen;
centralIntensity[2] = cred;
cout<<"I:["<<cx<<","<<cy<<"]="<<centralIntensity<<endl;
cout<<"***Uchar:["<<cx<<","<<cy<<"]="<<int(centralIntensity[0])<<","<<int(centralIntensity[1])<<","<<int(centralIntensity[2])<<endl;
cout<<"***Uchar:["<<cx<<","<<cy<<"]="<<int(cblue)<<","<<int(cgreen)<<","<<int(cred)<<endl;
```

I get:

> I:[70,700]=[150, 162, 160]
>
> ***Uchar:[70,700]=127,0,0
>
> ***Uchar:[70,700]=127,0,0

If I change coordinates?

> I:[300,400]=[109, 123, 105]
>
> ***Uchar:[300,400]=127,0,0
>
> ***Uchar:[300,400]=127,0,0

Comment: Please show this issue in a [mcve], as this works as expected (prints correct values) for me. Also make sure that `imgTemp` is a `CV_8UC3` and correctly initialized. If you explain what is your final goal, there is a good chance it can be achieved with a better approach than scanning the matrix explicitly.

Comment: why do you convert to int?

Comment: @orkan otherwise it will print the ascii characters, not the number

Comment: @Miki I have edited my question with a complete example. I would like to know why the values in the Vec3b components are the same?

Comment: where are you assigning `cblue`, `cgreen`, `cred`?

Comment: Just do `cblue = centralIntensity[0];` instead of `centralIntensity[0] = cblue;` etc...

Comment: oh... shame on me... I didn't notice. Write it as an answer, please.

Comment: already posted. Btw, if you actually tried your mcve, the debug would've told you the error :D

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `Mat*`, since you're very likely to break `Mat` internal reference counting.

Comment: So, is it better to make a copy with Mat::copyTo ?

Comment: It's better to avoid `Mat*`. And yes, for deep copies you can use `copyTo` or `clone`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `centralIntensity` with uninitialized values `cblue`, `cred`, `cgreen`, which will have *random* values inside.

Just correct the assignment:

```
cblue = centralIntensity[0];
cgreen = centralIntensity[1];
cred = centralIntensity[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

- For Vec3b , you can do it by this way,

  ```
  Mat image = imread("img_Path");
  for(int y=0;y<img.rows;y++)
  {
     for(int x=0;x<img.cols;x++)
     {
        // get pixel
        Vec3b color = image.at<Vec3b>(x, y);

        //color.val[0] // B
        //color.val[1] // G
        //color.val[2] // R
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ok. but the problem is that I see the same values for the components. See my edit, please.

Comment: @SagarPatel you shouldn't post an answer if the question is not well defined. Or your answer may be just useless, as this one. You can comment to the question for clarification before posting the answer.